# 1060 graphics card problematic on Linux

Tags: linux, graphics

I installed the latest driver for the graphics card which is Nvidia 390.48 but I suspect CPU is undertaking all the work. Even though my laptop is Asus GL703VM (high specs) my CPU gets heated for no reason with very light jobs, which had not happened while I was using Windows 10.

I tried searching about the problem but I'm a little ignorant when it comes to inner workings of graphics of a computer so I couldn't put a finger on the problem.

I use Linux Mint.

[broad view of the graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54GKW.jpg)

[detailed view of the graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OoQU.png)

Comment: I do not think the pictures you provided help describe the issue. Is the problem that the laptop is overheating or that you are using intel graphics instead of nvidia? please update your post with a reason why the pictures are relevant and include the output of `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"`

Comment: @kemotep well the pictures are far away from smoothness as opposed to what you would expect from nvidia 1060 gpu. The scale of exact same color in each pixel is very large that you feel like there are only 255 different colors supported by your OS.

Output is: OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 1060/PCIe/SSE2

Comment: So your operating system is using Nvidia for at least OpenGL rendering. If you use some other kind of renderer for graphical work you can grep for those instead to verify if the correct graphics card is being used. As for the CPU running hot what is the measured temperature? Idling at 40-50c is not unheard of for a laptop and some cooling features could potentially be tied behind drivers you have not installed that are more standard in your Windows install. I am not an expert on that however. Have you tried different backgrounds what do edges of applications look like? Is there screen tearing?